# Replace text with clickable text link open in new tab

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to replace a `text 1` with `text 2` in javascript.

`Text 2` should be clickable which lead to site X in a new tab.

The code I'm using to replace text:

```js
var search = "TEXT 1";
var replacement = "TEXT 2";
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.split(search).join(replacement);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `a` tag as string and `target='_blank'` to open the link in new tab.

```js
var search = "TEXT 1";
var replacement = "TEXT 2";

var replacementTag = "<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>"+replacement+"</a>";

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.split(search).join(replacementTag);
```

```html
TEXT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var search = "TEXT 1";
var replacement = "TEXT 2";
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.split(search).join(replacement);
```

Your Replacement code is fine enough to do the job of replacing all occurrences TEXT 1 with TEXT 2.

To make the resultant TEXT 2 as clickable, and pointing to site X, change the replacement variable to enclose the TEXT 2 within an anchor tag with href at site X's Address, and target as '_blank' to open link in a new window.

```
var search = "TEXT 1";
var replacement = "<a href='X Address goes here' target='_blank'>TEXT 2</a>";
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.split(search).join(replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` to replace `TEXT 1` with `TEXT 2` and to open the link in the new tab you have to use attribute `target='_blank'` in your anchor tag.

```js
var search = "TEXT 1";
var replacement = "<a href='https://www.google.com' target='_blank'>TEXT 2</a>";
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(search), replacement);
```

```html
some thing TEXT 1
```